# Centering tooltip to inline list box

Tags: css

as you can see in jsfiddle my tooltip boxes are working, but what is annoying is that they are not in the center. The boxes seem to be "almost centered" for lack of better words. Even though i am aligning it as center in the css code.

Thank you.

```css
li {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.horizontal-list a {
    float: left;
    width: 8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #0094ff;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
}

.horizontal-list a span {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    align-self: absolute;
}

.horizontal-list a:hover span {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #535663;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:absolute;
    margin-right:auto 0;
    margin-left:auto 0;
```

```html
<ul class="horizontal-list">
                <li><a href="Google.com"><img src="images.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="aaaaaa" /><span id="tooltipmain">aaaaaa</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="Google.com"><img src="images.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="aaaaaa" /><span>aaaaaa</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="aaaaaa" /><span>aaaaaa</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="aaaaaa" /><span>aaaaaa</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="aaaaaa" /><span>aaaaaa</span></a></li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ud2pajtb/7/
sorry for spelling errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `<span>`s are positioned absolutely, setting `margin:0 auto` won't center it relative to the parent element. Right now its alignment is basically based on its width, so to make the tooltip appear centered, increase its width slightly.

http://jsfiddle.net/xw3z1890/
Here I have simply set `<span>` width to 109px.